# Asp .NET 5 data annotation localization with a custom localizer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

I have created my own cached JSON string localizer by overriding `IStringLocalizerFactory` and `IStringLocalizer` and it works like a charm.

The only problem is that I can not localize data annotations because they seem to not work with a custom string localizer. I tried using the `ResourceType` property which should be used for exactly this case (at least as far as I am concerned), but instead of using my `IStringLocalizer` it tries to access properties. This might work with the default `resx`-localizer, but not with a custom one.

I could create properties in my class which reroute to my `IStringLocalizer` but thats a hassle and only want to do it this way if I have to.

My view model:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "test", ResourceType = typeof(Lang))]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

is used inside of my `cshtml` like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Username" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

which should autogenerate the `label` and the `textbox`. But instead:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed. Type 'Test.Models.Lang.Lang' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'test'.
```

booom. Thats my `Lang` class:

```
public class Lang
{
}
```

Instead of getting a `IStringLocalizer<Lang>` and searching for a `test` property via indexer (thats what I am trying to make him do), it tried to find the non-existing property `test`.

Is there any way to change the way the lookup works? I tried to changing the `MvcDataAnnotationsLocalizationOptions` via `services.Configure()`, but to no effect.

Or if it is possible to directly change the way the HTML-code is generated from those data-annotations?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This of course doesn't work because the CreateDisplayMetadata() is only called once and then cached, causing the first "translation" become the only one! I do have another solution extending the DefaultModelMetadataProvider or adding a IDisplayMetadataProvider (still not sure it's the right or best way to go...), so if anyone still needs help with this, please let me know :)

**OLD AND WRONG ANSWER:**
Don't know if there is any "more correct" (please let me know if so :) solution, but here is one that works in RC2:

```
public class LocalizedDisplayMetadataProvider : IDisplayMetadataProvider
{
    public String Translate(String key)
    {
        if(key != null && key.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            return key.TrimStart('#').ToUpper(); // Todo: Replace with real localization code (e.g. fetch from json)...
        }
        else
        {
            return key;
        }
    }

    public void CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
    {
        foreach(var attr in context.Attributes.OfType<DisplayAttribute>().Where(a => a.ResourceType == null))
        {
            attr.Name = this.Translate(attr.Name);
            attr.Description = this.Translate(attr.Description);
            attr.GroupName = this.Translate(attr.GroupName);
            attr.Prompt = this.Translate(attr.Prompt);
            attr.ShortName = this.Translate(attr.ShortName);
        }
    }
}
```

And then register in ConfigureServices method:

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(m =>
        {
            m.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new LocalizedDisplayMetadataProvider());

        });
```

This will localize all strings starting with '#' (and not ResourceType set) on the DisplayAttribute, and can easily be expanded to handle the ValidationAttribute as well.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. So, if I want to have DataAnnotations work dynamically (every time check for new localized versions), I should not rely on StringLocalizer is it? Is your LocalizedDisplayMetadataProvider still works ok? I am on .Net 5